# How to tell the filter views is using

Tags: 6, views

I'm in the process of writing a custom views filter handler. In order to learn from the existing filters, I'd like to know how I can tell which filter class views is using when I'm configuring an (exposed) filter on the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an exposed view filter inserts the following (sample) code into the view output:

```
 <div class="view view-... view-id-... view-display-id-default view-...-id-1">
    <div class="view-header">
        ...
    </div>

    <div class="view-filters">
        <form action="..." accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get" id="views-exposed-form-...">
        <div>
            <div class="views-exposed-form">
               <div class="views-exposed-widgets clear-block">
                  <div class="views-exposed-widget views-widget-filter-tid">
                     <label for="edit-tid">...</label>
                     <div class="views-widget">
                        <div class="form-item" id="edit-tid-wrapper">
                           <select name="tid" class="form-select" id="edit-tid" >
                              <option value="All">...</option>...
                           </select>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="views-exposed-widget views-submit-button">
                    <input type="submit" id="edit-submit-..." class="form-submit" />
                 ...
```

It is not clear, though, why you can't find out the same by simply creating a view, exposing its filter and looking up the source code. Perhaps you could explain your question better?

Comment: I think BetaRide is trying to create a custom filter in a module and then trying to implement a class into the field's output. So the question really is, how to define the class that gets attached to the HTML output through the module. That's my guess though.